# AES CTR Mode Encryption with HMAC

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to implement AES CTR encryption mode with HMAC authentication for messages.

It's encrypting and decrypting fine as long as the key length is 64 bytes, since AES key and HMAC key are being derived from this key.

### Questions

- Is it safe to append IV or nonce to the encrypted messages?
- Is it safe to append HMAC digest to append to the messages?

Using Pycryptodome

### Code

```
import os 
import zlib
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
import zlib 


def encrypt(full_key, plaintext):

    if len(full_key) != 64:
        raise Exception("FULL key length shall be equal to 64")
    key = full_key[:len(full_key) //2]

    # Use the last half as the HMAC key
    hmac_key = full_key[len(full_key) // 2:]


    if isinstance(plaintext, str):
        plaintext = plaintext.encode()

    compressed = zlib.compress(plaintext, 5)
    print (f"compressed plaintext {compressed}")



    # Choose a random, 16-byte IV.
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    # Convert the IV to a Python integer.
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16) 
    # Create a new Counter object with IV = iv_int.
    ctr = Counter.new(128, initial_value=iv_int)
    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
    # Encrypt and return IV and ciphertext.
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(compressed)


    hmac_obj = HMAC.new(hmac_key, compressed, SHA256)
    mac = hmac_obj.digest()

    return iv+ciphertext+mac


def decrypt(key, ciphertext):
    # Initialize counter for decryption. iv should be the same as the output of
    # encrypt().


    if len(full_key) != 64:
        raise Exception("FULL key length shall be equal to 64")

    key = full_key[:len(full_key) //2]

    # Use the last half as the HMAC key
    hmac_key = full_key[len(full_key) // 2:]

    mac_length = 32
    iv_length = 16
    iv = ciphertext[:16]
    mac = ciphertext[-mac_length:] 

    _ciphertext = ciphertext[iv_length:-mac_length]


    iv_int = int(iv.hex(), 16) 
    ctr = Counter.new(128, initial_value=iv_int)
    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

    ciphertext = aes.decrypt(_ciphertext)

    # Extract the MAC from the end of the file
    hmac_obj = HMAC.new(hmac_key, ciphertext, SHA256)
    computed_mac = hmac_obj.digest()

    if computed_mac != mac:
        raise Exception("Messege integrity violated")





    plaintext= zlib.decompress(ciphertext)

    # Decrypt and return the plaintext.


    return plaintext
```

Comment: The answer to both questions is: "of course, that is what they are designed for".

Comment: Shall i delete the question then, Provided both are best practices?

Comment: No, do not delete the question.

Comment: While there seems to be nothing wrong with your method, "best practice" today probably is to use AES-GCM with a 12-byte nonce. AES-GCM is a type of counter mode cipher that includes a built-in MAC calculation, eliminating the need for a separate MAC like HMAC.

Comment: Thats what we did, AES_GCM, then we coudnt find any good library on Fronted to decrypt the encrypted Text with AES_GCM mode. This is the best we could find https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js and it doesnt implement AES-GCM mode.

Comment: what is "Fronted"?

Comment: I misspelled ..its front-end .. I meant to say ..AES-GCM mode implementation in Javascript.